# Error with Tesseract js

Tags: javascript, html, ocr, tesseract.js

I need help with my script. I'm trying to generate a code that shows the text in an image and I found the library Tessereact.js, but when the use shows me this  error ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4hnw.png)):

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
```

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js/1.0.10/dist/tesseract.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="img/ley.jpg"/>
    <script>
        var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
        Tesseract.recognize(img, function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to please help, I am very interested in completing this project...

**Thank you!**

Comment: hi, did my answer address your question?

Answer (score 2):

Your image `img/ley.jpg` by right would be loaded into a canvas by `tessereact.js` to process further. However, due to the CORS policy, the canvas is "tainted" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image).

You can work around this by setting the `crossOrigin` of the image element to `Anonymous` provided that the server that hosts the image returns `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in the header.

Here is the working code

```js
var img = new Image;
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var src = "https://i.imgur.com/FkLGnxH.png";

img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

img.onload = function() {
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  Tesseract.recognize(ctx)
    .then(function(result) {
      document.getElementById("result")
        .innerText = result.text;
    });
}
img.src = src;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js/1.0.10/dist/tesseract.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <span id="result"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/comulejaqa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Amazing solution buddy, is there a way to get the width and height from the original source?